# error in loop with if statement, but gets compiled and terminates without error without displaying expected result

Tags: java, if-statement

While solving the question(It is in the code as comment.) The if statement (which displays the result) is not working. Please help me to figure out the error. It gets compiled and runs but output is not displaying.

```
/*
 * (Calculating the Value of π ) Calculate the value of π from the infinite series
         4     4     4     4      4
π = 4 – --- + --- – --- + --- – ------ + ...
         3     5     7     9      11
Print a table that shows the value of π approximated by computing the first 200,000 terms of this
series. How many terms do you have to use before you first get a value that begins with 3.14159?
 */
public class ValueOfPi 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i,count=0;
        double pi=0.0,n=1.0,PI=3.14159;
        for(i=0;i<200000;i++)
        {
            count++;
            if(count%2!=0)
            {
                pi=pi+(4/n);
            }
            else if(count%2==0)
            {
                pi=pi-(4/n);
            }
            n=n+2;
            if(pi==PI)
            {
                System.out.printf("terms=%d     PI=%f\n",count,pi);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason that that the if statement is not working is that you're comparing floating point numbers for equality. The page [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) explains why.

After rereading the OP's question, for this case I'd first convert the calculated value of pi to a string that is 8 or more characters long and compare the first 7 characters against "3.14159".

Comment: Thanks,but it will not work since the value of pi in each addition or subtraction of (4/n) increases or decrease the value of pie. for example, the first 10 count gives 4.000000, 2.666667, 3.466667, 2.895238, 3.339683, 2.976046, 3.283738, 3.017072, 3.252366, 3.041840. which is not serially in ascending or descending order.

Comment: try `if (Math.abs(pi - PI) < 0.000005)`

Answer (score 0):

First floating point is inprecise - an approximation of a sum of (negative) powers of two - (also with 3.14159), and the calculated `pi` can be above or below the given value.

Also use `%n` as `\n` is a Linux line end, not Windows where it is `\r\n`. This could have prevented the flushing of the line buffer to output. (Not sure, I have Linux).

```
        if (Math.abs(pi - PI) < 1.0E-5)
        {
            System.out.printf("terms=%d     PI=%f%n",count,pi);
            break;
        }
```

Also you might use `Math.PI` for a better approximation. You now risk to have a more precise `pi` than `PI` needing that 0.00001 imprecision.

Using == or a too small eps margin, like 0.00000001 might cause an almost infinite loop.